# How Select record with where clause with math using ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to return a list of records whose `created_at` more than 5 seconds before its `updated_at`

i.e.

```
Person.where("((people.updated_at - people.created_at) * 60 * 60 * 24) > ?" 5)
```

But this syntax doesn't appear to work. Getting the error:

```
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: That `people` looks suspicious in `people.updated_at` and `people.created_at`... Also, it looks like you're missing a comma here: `" 5`, like `", 5`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say what database you are using, but with MySQL you can the TIMEDIFF function for this:

```
Person.where("timediff(updated_at, created_at) > ?", '00:00:05')
```

If you are using Postgres:

```
Person.where("extract(epoch from updated_at) - extract(epoch from created_at) < ?", 5)
```

Comment: I like the second option. Working in seconds from epoch helps me keep things straight, especially across time zones.